# .load method callback not working

Tags: jquery

I'm using the load method to load multiple pages into a div. When the user clicks on a link with the href of a classname the function should load the specific div from that page into the #reveal div. I can only get it to work with one page. I'm using a callback to try and load multiple pages with the load method, but it's not working. Do I have to set some type of parameter? I want to use the load method because I can call specific divs and only load what I need.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $( '#show ul li a' ).click(function() {

        $( '#reveal' ).load( 'test.html .' + $(this).attr('href'), function() {
          $( '#reveal' ).load( 'page.html .' + $(this).attr('href'));

          });
          return false;
        });  
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: What are you expecting `$(this).attr('href')` to contain? It's very strange that you'd want to load a URL containing something like `"test.html .http://localhost/page.html"` with the extra dot and everything.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, the dot is meant to be the class selector. the load method allows you to call specific divs to be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things wrong with your code.

- You don't want to concatenate, `'test.html'` or `'page.html'` to `$(this).attr('href')`.  You only want to load `$(this).attr('href')`.
- You're calling the second load in the callback of the first load and overwriting the html in that `<div>`.  I don't think that's what you're after.

I think you're overcomplicating this and you can simplify your code down to this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( '#show ul li a' ).click(function() {
      $( '#reveal' ).load( $(this).attr('href') );
    });  
});
```

Comment: You sir are a lifesaver. Can't believe that never occurred to me. Then I can just call everything from the href.

Comment: @larryburns  No worries.  Glad that helped you out.